# How to convert current date to a specific 24h format?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'd like to convert the current date to the following 24h format:

```
2015-07-14T14:43:30,727
```

Tried the following:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSS"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

The problem is this doesn't work if the 24-Hour Time is turned off in the phone's (iPhone 6) Settings (i.e. the phone is set to 12h format).

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

try following code :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

HH means 24 hour format

hh means 12 hour format.

Comment: The output is still in the following 12h format:    2015-07-14 3:51:24 pm